# setText() not working on inflated layout

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I'm trying to inflate a `LinearLayout` to build a customized section on my screen.

```
String txt = "testing";
LinearLayout rowLink = (LinearLayout)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.additional_link, null);
TextView tvCsAddLink = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvCsAddLink);                                       
tvCsAddLink.setText(txt);

// adding this inflated layout to an existing layout
myLinearLayout.addView(rowLink);
```

The content of my `additional_link.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/llCsAddLink"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/white_row"
    android:clickable="true"
    >        
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/youtube_icon" />        
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCsAddLink"       
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingRight="20px"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm getting a `NullPointerException` on the line:

```
tvCsAddLink.setText(txt);
```

Comment: TextView tvCsAddLink = (TextView)rowLink.findViewById(R.id.tvCsAddLink);

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use this to get TextView from layout.

```
TextView tvCsAddLink = (TextView)rowLink.findViewById(R.id.tvCsAddLink);
```

Comment: After 9 years, this is still very useful! Thank you Arslan!

Answer (score 5):

you have inflated your XML on your `linearLayout` `rowLink`  , and you try to find the `TextView` from the layout of your `Activity` ( usualy `main.xml` ) , so you need to find your `textView` on your layout rowLink like this  :

```
TextView tvCsAddLink = (TextView)rowLink.findViewById(R.id.tvCsAddLink);
```

Answer (score 4):

Call `findViewById(R.id.tvCsAddLink)` on your inflated `LinearLayout`**rowLink**, now you are searching it in the current activity.